# Add the tax total as a separated row on Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I would like to edit the contents of the [Woocommerce invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7GXN.png)  that a customers gets after ordering. I think I have to edit this file located at wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php

Using the following code:

```
<tr>
    <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ?
 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : '';
 ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); ?></td>
```

Now it shows the VAT details on the same rule as the total price, but I would like it to be on a separate rule as follows:

```
Totaal: €50,00
BTW:    €8,68
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this change **on all email notifications**, you will use the following code, that will display the gran total (without displayed taxes) and the taxes in a separated new row:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'insert_custom_line_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function insert_custom_line_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    // Only on emails notifications
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {

        // Change: Display only the gran total amount
        $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = strip_tags( wc_price( $order->get_total() ) );

        // Create a new row for total tax
        $new_row = array( 'order_tax_total' => array(
            'label' => __('BTW:','woocommerce'),
            'value' => strip_tags( wc_price( $order->get_total_tax() ) )
        ) );

        // Add the new created to existing rows
        $total_rows += $new_row;
    }

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

If you want **to target only the "Customer invoice" email notification**, instead you will need to make changes on the template `emails/email-order-details.php` overriding it through your theme.

Please read first the documentation: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Once you have copied `emails/email-order-details.php` template file to your theme's folder, open/edit it.

On line 64 after:

```
            $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();
```

Add the following:

```
            // Only Customer invoice email notification
            if ( $email->id === 'customer_invoice' ):

            // Change: Display only the gran total amount
            $totals['order_total']['value'] = strip_tags( wc_price( $order->get_total() ) );

            // Create a new row for total tax
            $new_row = array( 'order_tax_total' => array(
                'label' => __('BTW:','woocommerce'),
                'value' => strip_tags( wc_price( $order->get_total_tax() ) )
            ) );

            // Add the new created to existing rows
            $totals += $new_row;

            endif;
```

Tested and works too…

Comment: would it be possible for you to please help me on this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009742/display-tax-as-a-separate-table-row-instead-with-totals-includes-tax-in-wo